# Put JPanel Form in JFrame using Card Layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I am creating a Java application. I have 2 Forms, one is `JFRAME FORM`, which contains left and right JPanel; and `JPANEL FORM` which contains the contents..

I am having trouble of putting the JPanel Form and its contents to the right JPanel of the JFRame form using card layout.

Comment: Are you using GUI Builder?

Comment: Will you show us your code?

Comment: Yes. I am using GUI Builder and I am creating an Application in Java Netbeans.

Comment: _"I am having trouble"_ - What kind of trouble. Please explain.

Comment: @peeskillet - I can't put the JPanel form on the Right JPanel I created in the JFrame Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already added the necessary space, for the right `JPanel` of the frame form, it's just  a matter of hand coding the addition of your `JPanel` form. something like this

```
public FrameForm extends JFrame {
    private PanelForm pForm = new PanelForm();

    public FrameForm() {
        initComponents();
        CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
        rightPanel.setLayout(card);

        rightPanel.add(pForm, "pForm");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! @peeskillet I accessed the JPanel as you instructed me, but the contents of the jComboBox(inside of the Jpanel) that comes from the database becomes empty. How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about.